# What are the benefits of using different certificates to identify the same service to different audiences?

Tags: authentication, certificates

Recently I was having a discussion with a team which uses a separate certificate for each different backend service that it interacts with. The backend services do client auth as well so that is what the certificates are used for.

I get that it reduces the blast radius when your certificate is leaked. But it also comes with additional management tasks. So I wonder, is there any other benefit that one gets?

Edit to clarify:
Say service A talks to B, C and D. Then service A will present certificate 1 as its identity to B, certificate 2 as its identity to C and so on. Certificate 1, 2 etc are all certificates representing service A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When acting as a client, a web service should act the same as a human client should do:

- should they present the same password to different services? **Never, ever**. Best practices recommend to have a different password per *authentication domain*. Only if various services share a common authentication service (OpenID connect for example), the password will be the same, because the user will consistentently authenticate on that shared service
- should they present different certificates? It depends. Some services will only accept client certificates that they deliver. For example my organization has provided me a certificate for my authentication on corporate services, and will never accept a certificate from a third party. Apart from that, as the server only knows the public key of the certificate, and as that key is err... *public*, there is no security problem in sharing a certificate among unrelated services.

Said differently presenting the same certificate to various services is not a security problem. But it may or not be possible for other organizational reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The point of certificates is identification and authentication - and on top of this often also access control. The point of having different certificates for different backends is to identify and authenticate each backend separately. While in static setup such identification might be done by IP address, in today's dynamic setups (cloud architectures) the IP is no longer known up-front or even static. A backend specific certificate can instead offer identification and authentication even in dynamic environments.

In a way having different certificates for different certificates is similar to having different user accounts and passwords for different users. While sharing accounts between users seems to be easier for management, it introduces obvious security problems: For one it increases the exposure of the secret password thus leads more likely to a account compromise. For another it allows only less granular access restrictions and accounting, i.e. only for a group of users and not a single user. Similar it is impossible to revoke access just for a single user from this group.

And the same is true for sharing the same certificate between different services. Thus the goal should not be to simplify management by sharing certificates or passwords, but to make using different certificates instead easy - i.e. automatic certificate enrollment, automatic certificate updates ...

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear. The certificates all belong to A. In your analogy, think of it as, same user, having different credentials for different websites.

Comment: @Limit: So this is about using different client certificates when visiting different web sites? These sites might have different requirements on what certificates they trust, so it might not be possible to reuse the same certificate. Also, depending on the software architecture a certificate might have encoded the role or the permissions the user has for this specific service, which might also favor to have one certificate per service to match the service specific role.